# how to match with multiple inputs elasticearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm trying to query all possible logs on 3 environments (dev,test,prod) with the below query using `terms`:  Tried `must` and `should`.

```
curl -vs -o -X POST http://localhost:9200/*/_search?pretty=true -d '
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
           "minimum_should_match": 1,
           "should": {
                "terms": {
                    "can.deployment": ["can-prod", "can-test", "can-dev"]
                }
            "filter": [{
                    "range": {
                        "@timestamp": {
                            "gte": "2020-05-02T17:22:29.069Z",
                            "lt": "2020-05-23T17:23:29.069Z"
                        }
                    }
            }, {
                    "terms": {
                        "can.level": ["WARN", "ERROR"]
                    }
            }, {
                    "terms": {
                        "can.class": ["MTMessage", "ParserService", "JsonParser"]
                    }
            }]
        }
    }
}'
```

gives:

```
{
  "took" : 871,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 391,
    "successful" : 389,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

However, if i replace `terms` with `match` it works. but can't query with the other inputs like query WARN messages, query logs related to ParserService class etc:

```
curl -vs -o -X POST http://localhost:9200/*/_search?pretty=true -d '
  {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": 
                [{"match": {"can.deployment": "can-prod"}}],
            "filter": [{
                    "range": {
                        "@timestamp": {
                            "gte": "2020-03-20T17:22:29.069Z",
                            "lt": "2020-05-01T17:23:29.069Z"
                        }
                    }
            },{
                    "match": {
                        "can.level": "ERROR"
                    }
            },{
                    "match": {
                        "can.class": "MTMessage"
                    }
            }
        ]
        }
    }
  }'
```

How do i accomplish this with or without terms/match.
Tried this, no luck. I get 0 search results:

```
                    "match": {
                        "can.level": "ERROR"
                    }
            },{
                    "match": {
                        "can.level": "WARN"
                    }
            },{
                    "match": {
                        "can.class": "MTMessage"
                    }
            }
```

Any hints will certainly help. TIA!

**[EDIT]**
Addings mappings (/_mapping?pretty=true):

```
          "can" : {
            "properties" : {
              "class" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "deployment" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "level" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
```

Adding sample docs:

```
{
  "took" : 50,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 391,
    "successful" : 387,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 5.44714,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "filebeat-6.1.2-2020.05.21",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "AXI9K_cggA4T9jvjZc03",
        "_score" : 5.44714,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2020-05-21T02:59:25.373Z",
          "offset" : 34395681,
          "beat" : {
            "hostname" : "4c80d1588455-661e-7054-a4e5-73c821d7",
            "name" : "4c80d1588455-661e-7054-a4e5-73c821d7",
            "version" : "6.1.2"
          },
          "prospector" : {
            "type" : "log"
          },
          "source" : "/var/logs/packages/gateway_mt/1a27957180c2b57a53e76dd686a06f4983bf233f/logs/gateway_mt.log",
          "message" : "[2020-05-21 02:59:25.373] ERROR can_gateway_mt [ActiveMT SNAP Worker 18253] --- ClientIdAuthenticationFilter: Cannot authorize publishing from client ThingPayload_4
325334a89c9 : not authorized",
          "fileset" : {
            "module" : "can",
            "name" : "services"
          },
          "fields" : { },
          "can" : {
            "component" : "can_gateway_mt",
            "instancename" : "canservices/0",
            "level" : "ERROR",
            "thread" : "ActiveMT SNAP Worker 18253",
            "message" : "Cannot authorize publishing from client ThingPayload_4325334a89c9 : not authorized",
            "class" : "ClientIdAuthenticationFilter",
            "timestamp" : "2020-05-21 02:59:25.373",
            "deployment" : "can-prod"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Expected output:
trying to get a dump of the whole document that matches the criteria. something like a above sample doc.

Comment: can you share ur mapping, sample docs and expected output?

Comment: added the details as suggested.

Comment: @james, I hv provided both the approaches and it would be great if you can go through them and provide feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
           "minimum_should_match": 1,
           "should": {
                "terms": {
                    "can.deployment": ["can-prod", "can-test", "can-dev"]
                }
            "filter": [{
                    "range": {
                        "@timestamp": {
                            "gte": "2020-05-02T17:22:29.069Z",
                            "lt": "2020-05-23T17:23:29.069Z"
                        }
                    }
            }, {
                    "terms": {
                        "can.level": ["WARN", "ERROR"]
                    }
            }, {
                    "terms": {
                        "can.class": ["MTMessage", "ParserService", "JsonParser"]
                    }
            }]
        }
    }
```

I suppose, the above search query din't worked because your fields `can.deployement`, `can.level` and `can.class` is a `text` field . If these were text field Elasticsearch analyzes these kind of fields by default standard analyzer, where it divides the text by stop words and converts all text in lowercase. You can refer more about it from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html).

For your case , for example `can.deployement` field value `can-prod` would be analyzed as

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "can",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 3,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "prod",
            "start_offset": 4,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

`Terms` query matches exact word(case sensitive search), but since elasticsearch analyzes your text and divide and converts into lowercase you are not able to find exact search text.

In order to solve this issue ,while creating your mapping of the index for these 3 fields (`can.deployement`, `can.level` and `can.class`) , you can create a `keyword` type of field which basically says to Elasticsearch to not to analyze this field and store it as it is.

You can create mapping for these 3 fields something like :

### Mapping :

```
 "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "can.class": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "can.deployment": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "can.level": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and now you can perform `terms` search using these keyword field :

### Search Query :

```
{ "query": {
        "bool": {
           "minimum_should_match": 1,
           "should": {
                "terms": {
                    "can.deployment.keyword": ["can-prod", "can-test", "can-dev"]
                }
           },
            "filter": [ {
                    "terms": {
                        "can.level.keyword": ["WARN", "ERROR"]
                    }
            }, {
                    "terms": {
                        "can.class.keyword": ["MTMessage", "ParserService", "JsonParser"]
                    }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

This, terms query will only work for case sensitive searches. You can refer more about it from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html).

Comment: @Preena Gupta, thank you for the answer! ["can-prod", "can-test", "can-dev"] is giving logs from "can-dev" and not from "can-prod", "can-test". but filters terms apprear to be wroking as expected. do you know how to fix this?

Comment: In your document as well can.deployment value is "can-prod" and "can-test" for which document value is not matching. Is it exact match ?

Comment: if i run the curl command with individual terms `"can.deployment.keyword": ["can-test"]` (or) `"can.deployment.keyword": ["can-dev"]` (with separate curl commands), it gives the matching documents.

Comment: Not sure. I have just tested with my test documents and it worked fine. Can you paste same doc for which is not fetched in result.

Comment: The document was posted on the question (sample document). It is the same for test, dev and prod. Just that the deployment name differs based on the log source. Doing separate curl worked so i guess that will do. Thank you!

Comment: @james thanks for accepting the answer, it would be great if you can upvote as well, by clicking the up arrow in my front of my answer :)

Comment: @james thanks to you , I would like you to go through my second approach provided as in second answer and give your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do case insensitive search you can use `match` query to do the same :

### Search Query :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {

            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "level": "warn error"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "class": "MTMessage ParserService JsonParser"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "deployment": "can-test can-prod can-dev"
                    }
                }

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This works because Elasticsearch by default analyzes your `match` query text with same analyzer as your index analyzer. Since in your case it is standard analyzer , it will convert this `match` query text in lowercase and remove stop words. You can read more about it from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html).

For example for search value `MTMessage ParserService JsonParser` it will get analyzed internally as :

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "mtmessage",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 9,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "parserservice",
            "start_offset": 10,
            "end_offset": 23,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "jsonparser",
            "start_offset": 24,
            "end_offset": 34,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

and since your values of document with this field also got analyzed in this way they will match.

Here one issue for this value `can-test can-prod can-dev` , it will get analyzed as :

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "can",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 3,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "test",
            "start_offset": 4,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "can",
            "start_offset": 9,
            "end_offset": 12,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "token": "prod",
            "start_offset": 13,
            "end_offset": 17,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 3
        },
        {
            "token": "can",
            "start_offset": 18,
            "end_offset": 21,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 4
        },
        {
            "token": "dev",
            "start_offset": 22,
            "end_offset": 25,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, if in your index this kind of document is there :

```
{
    "can.deployment": "can",
    "can.level": "WARN",
    "can.class": "JsonParser"

}
```

Then this document will also be shown in your search result.

So, based on what kind of search you want to perform and what kind of search data you have you can decide whether to use `terms` query or `match` query.